# OracleDataAdapter.Fill - retrieves columns but no rows

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle

Im loading Oracle SQL data to a datatable. Im using three different queries that work perfectly well in SQLDeveloper.

Code goes like this:

```
using (OracleConnection OracleConnection = new OracleConnection())
{
      //  OracleConnection = new OracleConnection();
      OracleConnection.ConnectionString = "<my_conn_string>";
      OracleConnection.Open();
      OracleDataAdapter reader = new OracleDataAdapter(query, OracleConnection);
      reader.Fill(result); 

      return result;
}
```

For 2 of the queries its fine but the 3rd one returns 0 rows and all columns. I have no idea what the problem may be. This query returns most rows (over 400) so I suspected it has something to do with maximum number of rows that Fill can process?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the rows are being returned? 400 is not a large amount..

Comment: Try posting you 3rd query whether the one that you execute in `SQLDeveloper` and in  your `code`. @stuartd : He said **"over"**. 1 trillion rows is more than 400 for sure :p

Comment: No no. We are talking about just over 400. 419 to be exact. The number is definitely not very high. I get some 48 Columns and 0 Rows.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently changing the order of the columns solved my issue... god one knows why but it works now perfectly!